# separate DateTime column in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a datetime column in a data frame (named `data`) like this:

```
data$Date_Time 

##[1] 14JUN2011:09:45:00
##[2] 15JUN2011:10:45:00
##[3] 16JUN2011:11:35:09
```

I'd like to obtain the date and time into separate columns.

For `Date`, it is easy to use:

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date_Time, format("%d%b%Y"))
```

But I am having trouble to get the `Time` column.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the POSIXt class for the time, which can be parsed like:

```
data$Time <- strptime(data$Date_Time, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

Also, I think that the date parsing should be:

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date_Time, format="%d%b%Y")
```

In other words, don't call the `format` function. You're just lucky that works anyway.

Comment: indeed is it possible just sort out the time for displaying the time using format %H:%M:%S idea? i m curious too.

Comment: Since POSIXt is meant to represent the time since the epoch, not the time of day, I'm not sure it really makes sense to only parse the time of day. If you stripped the date, it would default to today, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `substr(date$Date_Time, 11, 18)`